# Baking multiples objects at once

Tags: baking

Do you know how to bake multiple object at once?
I have 6 spheres 'Soft body" that I would like to bake is it possible to bake them in one shot? Or the all scene at once?

Thanks

Comment: there's a Bake All Dynamics button in the Bake panel but it will bake every physics I guess

Comment: Thanks but do not work